# Add a specific directory of svn to composer

Tags: wordpress, svn, composer-php

I just want this folder: https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes  (or the [github mirror](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/tree/master/tests/phpunit/tests)) and not the whole project.

I can get it with `svn co --quiet https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes wp-tests`

But since the whole project is managed by composer it's just annoying to do extra commands.

I obviously can't edit this repository.

What is the best way to add this folder to my project so it will be maintained with `composer update/install`. Preferably without adding my own stripped down mirror, which we would have to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define virtual package which will point to this directory and add it to `require-dev` section:

```
"require-dev": {
    "wordpress/phpunit": "*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "wordpress/phpunit",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://develop.svn.wordpress.org",
                "type": "svn",
                "reference": "trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/@43534"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Package will be installed in `vendor/wordpress/phpunit`. You can change this directory by using [`composer/installers`](https://github.com/composer/installers) plugin.

Comment: Yes something like this was what I was looking for, Can I change the revision to always be the latest?

Comment: Repositories defined as `package` are static. It means that composer will not automatically update data from SVN repository - you need to bump package `version` to reflect actual change. You can remove revision number (`@43534`) from `reference` but it will only make this less predictable - this type does not really work well with actively developed libraries. If you always need a fresh code, you should probably install whole package from https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop  - it should not be a big problem if it will be only dev dependency.

Comment: In the other hand this directory is not changed that often, managing this manually should no be a big problem: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/commits/master/tests/phpunit/includes

Answer (score 1):

You could use composer's `post-update-cmd` or `post-install-cmd` option. This is executed after a composer update/install. Add this to composer.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "svn co --quiet https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes wp-tests",
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Interessting, The [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) mention can also check for `COMPOSER_DEV_MODE` variable.
I'll check if better suggestions get posted but I guess this can be acceptable.

Comment: This will always install most recent version from repo. In some cases this may be undesirable - update from repo may break your tests. There should be revision specified to make this more predictable.